# Error while deploying firebase function which creates agora token

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, agora.io

I have tried many things to deploy this function, installing and uninstalling node many times and many more tries but it still giving me same error.
What I am trying to achieve is **using agora-access-token package to generate token using firebase function**
the code is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {RtcTokenBuilder, RtcRole} = require("agora-access-token");

exports.agoraToken = functions.region("asia-south1").
    https.onCall((data, context)=> {
      const appID = "<myAppID>";
      const appCertificate = "myAppCertificate";
      const uid = data.uid;
      const channelId = data.channelId;
      const role = RtcRole.PUBLISHER;

      const expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600;
      const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      const privilegeExpiredTs = currentTimestamp + expirationTimeInSeconds;
      const token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appID,
          appCertificate, channelId, uid, role, privilegeExpiredTs);
      return token;
    });
```

And the error is:

> === Deploying to 'xxxx'...
>
> I  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR"
> run lint
>
> > lint
> > eslint .
>
> - functions: Finished running predeploy script. i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... i
>   functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is
>   enabled... i  functions: ensuring required API
>   artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
> - functions: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
> - functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
> - functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... i
>   functions: packaged functions (71.53 KB) for uploading
> - functions: functions folder uploaded successfully i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function agoraToken(asia-south1)...
>
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
> agoraToken(asia-south1) i  functions: cleaning up build files...
>
> Error: There was an error deploying functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I did not added dependency in package.json file. I had to add agora-access-token dependency in package.json in function folder.

Edit:
As I faced difficulty in this process I have created GitHub repository having sample code for creating Agora Access Token using Firebase Functions. https://github.com/rushikeshnarwade/agora-access-token-using-firebase-functions

Comment: Good to know that you found the solution, did my answer help you to get the exact error to solve the problem ?

Comment: please can show me your request.. i use your code but is given me error

Comment: Would you please share the package.json code?

Comment: @FaizanAhmad you can find whole code with comments here https://github.com/rushikeshnarwade/agora-access-token-using-firebase-functions

Answer (score 0):

What I can propose is that you use `--debug` because it provides information not found in the logs , and it can also fix a problematic deployment.

Try running the deployment with --debug.
Example: `firebase --debug deploy.`

Cloud Function logs can be seen in the Firebase dashboard, the Cloud Logging UI, or the firebase command-line tool.

To view more logs, here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs) to the documentation.

Comment: The problem was not defining the agora-access-token dependency in package.json file in function folder.